# js - switch element ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, element

I want to change 2 div ids up.

```
val = [
   ["one","two"],
   ["two","one"]
];
    sub = [];
    for(i in val)
    {
        sub = val[i];
        if($(e.target).is("#"+sub[0]))
        {
             $("#"+sub[0]).attr({"id", sub[1]});
        }
    }
```

These two divs don't exist at the same time. But this code still doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

//Edit

I've tested with class. And It still doesn't work. What happens?

I've also tested with a deleted suggestion of each loop. And It worked, but just with the very first value of val.

Comment: You should use classes. IDs are not for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
attr({"id", sub[1]});
```

should be :

```
attr("id", sub[1]);
```

Though I agree with everyone else there is probably a better way to do this using either attributes or class names.

Also, if this is in a click event handler or some other bound event handler, and depending on how it is bound, you might be able to replace:

```
if($(e.target).is("#"+sub[0]))
```

with

```
if($(this).attr(id) == sub[0])
```

Comment: `$(e.target)` is not necessarily the same as `$(this)`.

Comment: true it depends on how the click event is bound.

Answer (score 0):

classes are for multiple divs (as in your case), ID's are for just a single div.

Comment: But these two divs don't exist at the same time. I said.

Comment: Even then, ID's can't be used multiple times, try using classes, it is as simple as ID's!

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
var a = document.getElementById('one');
var b = document.getElementById('two');
a.id = 'two';
b.id = 'one;
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit?